# What system data can I purge from my LG Tribute Android phone?

Tags: internal-storage, system

I own an LG Tribute Android phone, with Virgin Mobile service.  The phone has 4 GB of storage and despite the fact I only have a handful of apps installed (Acrobat Reader, Starbucks, OpenTable, Skype, Uber), I have run out of storage on my phone.  Here is the breakdown ...

```
Available - 124 MB
Apps - 1.45 GB
Pictures, videos - 112 MB
Audio - 148 KB
Downloads - 336 KB
Cached data - 13.8 MB
System data - 2.3 GB
```

What system data can I delete wihtout screwing up my phone and how can I do that?

Comment: Freeing up system memory by deleting system apps might not help *in my opinion*. You wouldn't be really able to use it... The partition size will not change by deleting bloatware so you'll gain next to nothing.

Comment: My question references system "data" so if there are other things I can delete besides apps to free up disk space (not memory, don't care about memory), what is safe to delete?